# Do nothing on empty textbox when enter is pressed

Tags: jquery

I have a form in which I have a textbox and a button. When the textbox is empty, and the user clicks the button or presses the enter key, it should do nothing. It should not show any error either. What's the best way to do this? I don't want to disable the enter key altogether.

```
<form id="search-form" name="search-form" method="get" action="search.php">

                    <input type="text" id="search" name="search"/>
                    <input type="submit"name="search-submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this, use jQuery's [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) to capture when the form is being submitted *(clicking the button or pressing enter will be captured with the [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) function)*, then test the search input is empty *(an empty string will return false)* and use the [`.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) function to stop the form being submitted.

```
$('#search-form').submit(function(e) {
   if (!$('#search').val()) {
       e.preventDefault();
   }       
});
```

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/GgEZc/)

Answer (score 9):

```
<input type="text" name="mytext" onkeypress="return event.keyCode!=13">
```

Comment: Wouldn't this disable the enter key indefinitely? I don't want to disable it. I just don't want anything to happen on keypress or submit button when the textbox is empty. Similar to what Google does.

Comment: No this would not disabled it indefinitely. this returns false (stopping the event) if the key pressed while in the text box is enter. Otherwise it returns true. It's almost the same thing as Alex's answer, only this applies it to a single element and doesn't use jQuery. But it only fires when the key is pressed, and it only affects the event at that time.

Comment: Scoobler's answer is better, as it is not inline. I failed to notice the jQuery tag and assumed my best bet was giving a non-jQuery solution.

Comment: This worked. I am still able to enter values into the field, but the enter action on this field does not do anything. just the way I wanted. Thanks BumbleShrimp :)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$("#search").keydown(function(e) {
  if($(this).val() == "" && e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

Comment: I tried this. Doesn't work. You can check the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/UVjpS/

Comment: Sorry should have been `val()`. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

On ASP.NET 2012
`onkeydown="return event.keyCode!=13"` was working right.